# Eevee renderer bug or intentional?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

EDIT: apparently i have been a dingus and not apply a texture.

The image shows blender and just a single frame i rendered from it. I originally tried to use cycles for rendering but for some reason it did not animate at all so I had wasted 30 minutes of waiting. Next I tried eevee rendering engine and then it animated fine, but it seems the plane and cube are transparent. Is this something bizarrely intentional, a bug, or am I just going insane and i got this image from a graphing calculator
[image]

Comment: Please don't add 'fixed' to the title. Either upvote and accept an existing answer which solves your issue or, if none of the answers solve your issue, add your own answer in the answer box below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but it looks as if the light in your scene may be set with too high a strength, washing out the results. Check to see what the strength setting is on your light by selecting it in Object Mode and looking at the Object Data tab in the Properties Panel. You can also turn on the rendering viewport setting by holding the z key and choosing Rendering from the pie menu popup. Changing this setting will allow you to see what you can expect visually from your adjustments to this light before committing to an actual render. Hope this helps.

Comment: I realized my lights strength was high, then i removed the light, yet it was still happening. the thing is, the render wasnt white and grey, but rather was grey with that transparent checkerboard look to it. and if i dragged the image with the middle mouse button it would seem to be transparent.

Comment: You removed the light and *what* was still happening? The bright whiteness? Or the dark grayness? If you're seeing checkerboard anything during rendering, then maybe something is going on with textures. Did you create any?

Comment: It looks like you have indeed created a texture, according to your pic. A procedural one. With no more to go on, and with so many possible causes for your issues,  you might need to either provide more details or upload the blend file.

Comment: I havent applied the texture just yet, so now I will, and im going to see if that works.

Comment: Ok so I applied the texture and rendered just a frame of it, and turns out I've just been a dingus.

Comment: You mentioned also removing the light. I wouldn't recommend removing lights to test lighting effect changes, but rather, modifying their settings. Especially since you may have only had one light to begin with. If you removed the only light you have, this is going to make your render very dark and nigh useless. Something to keep in mind.